# Finding average per integer compared to each element in a given list

Tags: python

So I'm practising data processing of a survey of 3 people for 21 questions.I need to give the average answer given per #.I'm not sure how to separate the numbers AND compare while leaving the letters out.

```
name=["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
      "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
      "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]
```

Eg. 1=4.33

My attempt:

```
def most_frequent(name):  

    counter = 0
    num = name[0]  
    for i in range (len(name)): 
        curr_frequency = name[0].count(str(i)) 
        if(curr_frequency> counter): 
            counter = curr_frequency 
            num = i 
    return num
```

Comment: How did the data end up like this in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
name=["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
      "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
      "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]

for line in name :
    parts = line.split()  # using space as a separator
    word = parts[0]       # extract the word
    numbers = map( float, parts[1:] )   # convert the numbers

    print( word, numbers )
    # now you may calculate whatever you want =)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the average of the numbers per #, what you can try is this, without having to split the line every time in a loop.

```
name = ["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
  "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
  "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]
name = [name[i].split(" ") for i in range(len(name))]
for i in range(1, len(name[0])):
    print((int(name[0][i])+int(name[1][i])+int(name[2][i]))/3, sep = " ")
```

Comment: Line 18, NameError: name 'i' is not defined?

Comment: Thanks a lot, how do I add 1./2./3. etc before each average, like original example?

Comment: You can see that all three alternate elements are being added in before printing, what you will get by this piece of code is the average of all 21 different elements(1, 2, 3) printed with a spacing between them. You might want to run this code to find out.

Comment: Yes, I believe there was confusion in my early comment, what I mean is to order from 1-21 the average for each in form (1.4.3/2.3.4, etc)

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get it, Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @AdmiralPyro You can use a for loop, for i in range(0, len(list)) : str(i) + str(list[i])

Comment: I get (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '') for the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
name=["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
      "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
      "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]
Average = Counter() 
length = 0
for item in name:
    thelist = item.split(' ')[1:]
    length += len(thelist)
    Average += Counter(thelist)
print(Average)

print([(i, Average[i] / length * 100.0) for i in Average])
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({'2': 18, '1': 17, '4': 14, '5': 7, '3': 7})

[('4', 22.22222222222222), ('2', 28.57142857142857), ('1', 26.984126984126984), ('5', 11.11111111111111), ('3', 11.11111111111111)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple for loop to remove the spaces and letters from the list.

You can use the `sum()` function on a list to get the sum of that full list, and then divide by the `len()` of the list to get the average.

This should work :

```
name=["AAAAA 4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5", "BBB 5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2", "K 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]

for i in range(0, len(name)) :

    tempOut = []

    temp = list(name[i])

    for j in range(0, len(temp)) : #65 - 123

        if ord(temp[j]) not in range(65, 122) :

            tempOut.append(temp[j])

    name[i] = ''.join(tempOut)

sums = []

for i in range(0, len(name)) :

    sumTemp = []

    temp = list(name[i].replace(' ', ''))

    for j in range(0, len(temp)) :
        sumTemp.append(int(temp[j]))

    tempSums = sum(sumTemp)/len(temp)

    sums.append(tempSums)
```